Extracting Time from Date/Time attribute in Snowflake
I have a column whose data is formatted like this: '2024-05-26 10:00:00.000'
I want to be able to extract the time so it is formatted like this: '10:00:00'
Any thoughts? Assuming there is an obvious keyword somewhere that I'm missing because there has to be an easier option than extracting everything separately and then concatenating it all together.

Use TO_CHAR function in SQL, which will allow you to format a datetime  value as a string.
Something like this would work:
SELECT TO_CHAR(column_name, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS time_only
FROM your_table;


Hello Selaka, I tried the following code:
TO_CHAR(SHIFT_STARTDATETIME, 'HH24:MI:SS') SHIFT_START_TIME
And received the following error message:
Error: too many arguments for function [TO_CHAR(HRS.SHIFT_STARTDATETIME, 'HH24:MI:SS')] expected 1, got 2 (line 9)

Nevermind, had to convert column to time stamp first and then it worked, thanks for the help!

Appreciate if you can mark it as correct answer or give an upvote for the answer :) happy to help
